# How to get the current path of compiled binary from Python using Nuitka?

Tags: python, nuitka

Nuitka is good at compiling Python to excutable binary.
But the compiled binary finds other resource files from original absolute path.
Thus, for moving to another computer requires to make the directory tree **same** as the original one.

For example, if I compile a project like this:

```
/home/me/myproj/
╠═ myprog.py
╚═ resource
   ╚═ foo.data
```

I should put the resulting binary and resource to the same location of another computer.
How to solve this problem?

My simpler spike is:

```
# /home/me/myproj/spike.py
import os
print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

And after compiling it, moving to any other location, I always got the result of `/home/me/myproj`.

I need a result like `/another/path` if I move compiled `myproj.bin` to `/another/path`.

Comment: See [How to control `__file__` location](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/467)

Comment: Thanks, it works as you said.

Comment: That's good to hear…you're welcome. Most Python compilers provide some way of doing/controlling what's in `__file__` as it's a fairly common way to do something like this.

Comment: Thanks. I searched on it for a couple of days and found no clear answers. And so much glad to be answered so quickly. Really, thanks. I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429101/nuitka-compiled-web-app-raises-error-on-exit). I wish your help again.

Answer (score 5):

Try using ***sys.argv[0]*** with ***os.path.abspath*** instead of `__file__` .

For example:

```
abs_pth = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
your_dir = os.path.dirname(abs_pth)

for val in abs_pth,your_dir:
    print(val)
```

This will help you get the current path to the executable binary file, as well as work with directories located in the same folder.

https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#onefile-finding-files

> There is a difference between `sys.argv[0]` and `__file__` of the main
> module for onefile more, that is caused by using a bootstrap to a
> temporary location. The first one will be the original executable
> path, where as the second one will be the temporary or permanent path
> the bootstrap executable unpacks to. Data files will be in the later
> location, your original environment files will be in the former
> location.

```
# This will find a file near your onefile.exe
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "user-provided-file.txt"))
# This will find a file inside your onefile.exe
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "user-provided-file.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good function to resolve `__file__` problem, it is to use `--standalone` flag, which create one main ".bin" file + other ".so" dependencies in one folder.

```
python -m nuitka --standalone program.py
```

https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#use-case-4-program-distribution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).